# Checking whether a Word .docx document has been fully loaded

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have big Word documents that load approximately 10 seconds each. I don't want to use Wait method, because it's not optimal and risky. For Internet Explorer I use:

```
Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And ie.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop
```

I would like to use the same for Word document or Word application, I have them dimensioned as objects, but they don't support such properties.

Comment: Is there some sort of call on a Word object that isn't blocking for you?  `Documents.Open` shouldn't return until the document is open.

Comment: Can you explain what it is that you are actually trying to achieve? Why do you need to wait? As @Comintern already said, the call to `Documents.Open` is blocking.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is possible, but with using both an object or a WordDocument object I couldn't recreate my error.